# Объект в store vuex теряет параметры

Tags: vue.js, typescript, vuex

всем.
Есть так называй системный стэк

```
import { PianoMenu, DEFAULT_MENU } from "@/core/ui/menu/PianoMenu";

export interface SystemStack {
  piano: PianoMenu;
  startWork: Date;
}

export class DefaultSystemStack implements SystemStack {
  piano: PianoMenu = DEFAULT_MENU;
  startWork: Date = new Date();
}
```

В котором храниться боковое меню и дата создания.
Есть хранилище, который содержит инфу о системном стэке

```
import { Module } from "vuex";
import { RootState } from "@/core/store/Types";
import { SystemStack, DefaultSystemStack } from "@/core/system/SystemStack";
import { getters } from "./getters";
import { actions } from "./actions";
import { mutations } from "./mutations";

export const state: SystemStack = new DefaultSystemStack();

const namespaced = true;

export const systemStack: Module<SystemStack, RootState> = {
  namespaced,
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations
};
```

В хранилище описаны actions

```
import { ActionTree } from "vuex";
import { RootState } from "@/core/store/Types";
import { SystemStack } from "@/core/system/SystemStack";
import { MenuGroup } from "@/core/ui/menu/PianoMenu";

export const actions: ActionTree<SystemStack, RootState> = {
  initSystemStack({ commit }, newStack: SystemStack): any {
    commit("initializeSystemStack", newStack);
  },
  addMenuGroup({ commit }, menuGroup: MenuGroup): any {
    commit("configStackAddMenuGroup", menuGroup);
  }
};
```

Так же мутации

```
import { SystemStack } from "@/core/system/SystemStack";
import { MenuGroup } from "@/core/ui/menu/PianoMenu";

export const mutations: MutationTree<SystemStack> = {
  initializeSystemStack(state, newStack: SystemStack) {
    state = newStack;
  },
  configStackAddMenuGroup(state, menuGroup: MenuGroup) {
    state.piano.addGroup(menuGroup);
  }
};
```

При старте системы в методе mounted() вызываю инициализацию стэка по умолчанияю, а потом добавляю свои пункты меню.

```
export default class App extends Vue {
  @ProcessAction executeProcess: any;
  @SystemStackAction addMenuGroup: any;
  @SystemStackAction initSystemStack: any;
  @JournalAction addInfoEvent?: any;

  drawer = true;
  menu = false;
  empty = [0];

  mounted() {
      this.initSystemStack(new DefaultSystemStack());
      this.addMenuGroup(GROUP_CUSTOM_MENU);
  }
}
</script>
```

Так вот, при инициализации стэка по умолчанию в state прописывается параметр `piano: PianoMenu`, но когда я добавляю новую группу меню, то падает ошибка из-за того, что параметр `piano` является `undefined`. Может мне кто-то подскажет, как такое выходит, что в state в начале всё заноситься, а потом куда пропадает? При этом время инициализации (параметр `startWork`) не меняется

Answer (score 0):

Немного покапавшись, я нашёл в чём была моя ошибка. Я пытаюсь переписать state, а это получается нельзя делать (где-то в документации это скорее всего прописано), а вот менять отдельные параметры state пожалуйста.